# Как найти любой определенный объект на фото?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Каким образом можно найти любые (определенные) объекты на фото или видео? Извините за тупость вопроса, но погуглив ничего толком ни нашел. Может быть есть библиотеки? Спасибо.

Comment: Что-же и как вы Гууглили? Ну вот, просто на вскидку: https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-simplified-e07aa3830954 https://towardsdatascience.com/detailed-tutorial-build-your-custom-real-time-object-detector-5ade1017fd2d https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/08/2019-guide-object-detection.html https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/18/face-recognition-with-opencv-python-and-deep-learning/ https://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-9dc039a2596b Пока хватит на первое время, надеюсь.